# How to avoid the repetition of "of"?

Tags: repetition

I work in marketing and I often have to present results of analysis.
The problem is my sentences often contain a lots of "of" !

How can I avoid the repetition in this kind of sentence :

- 10 % **of** the customers **of** this brand are...
- 20% **of** the students **of** this school would like to ...

Comment: You could rearrange... "10% of this brand's customers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *possessives* instead. Your examples could be rewritten thusly:

- 10% of *this **brand's** customers* are...
- 20% of *this **school's** students* would like to...

This is not the only way to do so, but using possessives should be flexible enough to work in most (if not all) situations you find yourself coming across.

Answer (score 0):

Turn one of the "of" phrases into a possessive form.

> 10 % of this brand's customers are...

or

> 20% of this school's students would like to ...